# Evaluating an infinite sum involving possibly hypergeometric terms

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, riemann-zeta, hypergeometric-function

I was considering the following infinite sum

$$ A(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{k+n-1}}{k^n}(0k -1)(k-1)(2k-1)...((n-1)k-1) \right] $$

Some cases:

$$ A(1) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \right]= -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} ... = \ln(2) - 1 $$

A trickier sum to evaluate is: $A(2)$. This resolves to:

$$ A(2) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{k^2} (k-1)\right] = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{9} + \frac{3}{16} ... $$

Some jugglery is required but if we consider

$$ 1 - x + x^2 -x^3 ... = \frac{1}{1+x}$$

And integrate

$$ \ln(1+x) = x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + ... $$

Divide by x and integrate

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx   = x - \frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{9} x^3 ... $$

Now multiply by (-1), divide by x and differentiate

$$ - \left( \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx \right)' = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{9} x + \frac{3}{16} x^2 ... $$

Meaning

$$ \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx  - \frac{1}{x}  \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \right)_{@x = 1} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{9} + \frac{3}{16} ...  $$

Through very mysterious techniques of the omniscient Wolfram Alpha this evaluates to

$$ \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \ln(2) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{9} + \frac{3}{16} ...  $$

So now this is totally in the deep end, but I have a suspicion the sum I have given can somehow be related to the riemann zeta function, in some good quality closed form. It's a wild guess but the $\ln(2)$ and now the $\pi^2$ hint me that's a good idea.

How to show this?

---

In case it's helpful

I tried to bash this with Sister Celine's method. By writing as

$$ A(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{k+n-1}}{k^n}(0k -1)(k-1)(2k-1)...((n-1)k-1) \right] = \sum_{k=2}[ M(n,k) ]  $$

And tried to find a recurrence for $M$ but unfortunately after consider $a_0(n) M(n,k) + a_1(n) M(n+1,k) + a_2(n) M(n-1,k) $ it became clear I'm going to need some more terms (possibly a lot more) before I can find a closed recurrence. Unfortunately my maple package has expired (I did send them an email to renew!) so I couldn't throw the might of Shalosh B. Ekhad in the Zeilberger package to close it up.

I suspect though that this would be ample for those techniques.

Comment: Now you got the answer ! I think that we must really thank Raymond Manzoni for his great contribution ! Happy end of a nice story !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick should be to rewrite (for $n>0$)
\begin{align}
A(n) &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+n-1}}{k^n}(0k -1)(k-1)(2k-1)...((n-1)k-1)\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac 1k\right)\left(\frac 1k-1\right)...\left(\frac 1k-(n-1)\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac 1k\right)_n\\
\end{align}

where $(x)_n$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) ("falling factorial") and a generating function for the [signed Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number#Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) (the term $\,i=0\,$ is omitted since $\;s(n,0)=0\,$ for $n>0$) :
$$(x)_n=\sum_{i=1}^n s(n,i)\,x^i$$
this gives (for $\,\eta\,$ the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) or "alternating zeta function") :
\begin{align}
A(n) &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^n s(n,i)\,\frac 1{k^i}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n s(n,i)\,\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} \frac 1{k^i}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n s(n,i)\,(\eta(i)-1)\quad\text{but}\quad  \sum_{i=1}^n s(n,i)=0\quad\text{for}\;n>1\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n s(n,i)\,\eta(i)\quad\text{for}\;n>1\quad\text{and}\quad s(1,1)(\eta(1)-1)\quad\text{for}\;n=1\\
\\
A(n)&= \begin{cases}s(n,1)\,\log(2)+\sum_{i=2}^n s(n,i)\left(1-2^{1-i}\right)\zeta(i),&n>1\\
\log(2)-1,&n=1\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Since $\;s(n,1)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\;$ these expressions are in perfect agreement with the table exposed by Claude Leibovici.

Comment: This is just fantastic ! I checked and it works perfect. Thanks again for taking the time. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks for the check and the appreciation @Claude! Excellent continuation!

Comment: Is $\left(1-2^{1-i}\right)\zeta(i)$ the Dirichlet $\eta(i)$ function ?

Comment: @Claude: yes it is [Dirichlet eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) as proposed in Kelenner's answer (the 'alternate' zeta sum).

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Interested by the post, I first wrote (from definition) $$A_n=\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+n} }{k}\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)_{n-1}$$ where appears the Pochhammer symbol.

Then, "playing" with a CAS, I obtained the following terms $$A_1=-1+\log (2)$$ $$A_2=\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-\log (2)$$ $$A_3=\frac{3 \zeta (3)}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}+2 \log (2)$$ $$A_4=-\frac{9 \zeta (3)}{2}+\frac{11 \pi ^2}{12}+\frac{7 \pi ^4}{720}-6 \log (2)$$ $$A_5=\frac{105 \zeta (3)}{4}+\frac{15 \zeta (5)}{16}-\frac{25 \pi ^2}{6}-\frac{7 \pi
   ^4}{72}+24 \log (2)$$ $$A_6=-\frac{675 \zeta (3)}{4}-\frac{225 \zeta (5)}{16}+\frac{137 \pi ^2}{6}+\frac{119
   \pi ^4}{144}+\frac{31 \pi ^6}{30240}-120 \log (2)$$ $$A_7=1218 \zeta (3)+\frac{2625 \zeta (5)}{16}+\frac{63 \zeta (7)}{64}-147 \pi
   ^2-\frac{343 \pi ^4}{48}-\frac{31 \pi ^6}{1440}+720 \log (2)$$

As you suspect, beside the $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\log(2)$ term, $A_n$ is a linear combination of $\zeta(.)$ functions $$A_n=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\log(2)+\sum_{i=2}^{n}a_i\, \zeta(i)$$

At this point, may I confess that I am totally stuck ?

**Edit**

Just for clarity, defining $$B_n=A_n-(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\log(2)$$ and back to only $\zeta(.)$ functions, we would have $$B_2=\frac 12 \zeta(2)$$ $$B_3=-\frac 32 \zeta(2)+\frac 34 \zeta(3)$$ $$B_4=\frac{11 }{2}\zeta(2)-\frac{9 }{2}\zeta (3)+\frac{7 }{8}\zeta(4)$$ $$B_5=-25 \zeta(2)+\frac{105 }{4}\zeta (3)-\frac{35 }{4}\zeta(4)+\frac{15 }{16}\zeta (5)$$ $$B_6=137 \zeta(2)-\frac{675
   }{4}\zeta (3)+\frac{595 }{8}\zeta(4)-\frac{225 }{16}\zeta (5)+\frac{31 }{32}\zeta(6)$$ $$B_7=-882 \zeta(2)+1218 \zeta (3)-\frac{5145 }{8}\zeta(4)+\frac{2625 }{16}\zeta (5)-\frac{651 }{32}\zeta(6)+\frac{63 }{64}\zeta
   (7)$$

Comment: This has been most enlightening. I actually don't know whether there is an answer to this question, so I just sit and hope. But at least it seems A finite Difference Integral of the zeta function will help.

Comment: The leading zeta terms appear to be of the form $\frac{4^n-1}{4^n}$

Comment: For the odd $A_i$

Comment: I was just noticing that !!

Comment: @frogeyedpeas and Claude: dividing the last column by $\,(1-2^{-n})\,$ you obtained simply $1$. Do the same thing for $[3,18,70,225,651]$ (with $n=1$ for $B_3$ this time) then you'll get $[3, 6, 10, 15, 21]$ i.e. $(n+1)(n+2)/2$. Do the same thing for the next diagonal and you'll get the Stirling numbers of the first kind $[11, 35, 85, 175]$ i.e.  $s(n+2,n)$. This [Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Table_of_values_for_small_n_and_k) should help to get the complete answer using these signed Stirling numbers.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Long time no speak ! I was really hoping that you look at this problem. This is a great answer. Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: Here, $\ln2$ represents the regularized value of $\zeta(1)$. In other situations, it's $\gamma$, since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\zeta(1+x)+\zeta(1-x)}2=\gamma$.

Comment: Glad it helped @Claude! Excellent continuation and cheers,

Comment: all of the diagonals are stirling numbers of the first kind, offset by 2,3,4,5 and I believe the pattern continues

Comment: It's seems very simple but I'm baffled in how to prove it at the moment.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas. Same for me ! May be you could ask  Raymond Manzoni for more assistance.

Comment: @Claude: I added an answer (without numerical verification I'll admit so hoping it's not too wrong...). Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if what follows is of some help, but:
Note that $\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(jk-1)=P_n(k)$, is a polynomial in $k$. Put $P_n(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$, then your sum is
$$A(n)=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_j(\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{n-j}})$$
and $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{s}}=\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Generalizations, ( in "the functional equation" part)

The case $j=n-1$ gives you the $\log(2)$ term, up to a constant due to the $k\geq 2$.

Comment: So this definitely must have rational function partial fractions. Ugh, it's irritating to know there's an algorithm to give the answer but I have to wait till earliest Monday to use it.

Comment: For sure, this explains that and shows that $A_n$ is a linear combination of $\zeta(.)$. I have been trying to find a pàattern in the $a_i$'s and I totally failed ! Any idea ? Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. No, I think I have previously encounter these sort of polynomials, and I did not find any formula for the coefficients, sorry. Bonne journée.

Comment: Have a good day too !! Where are you ?